# Python Discord bot give roles on join

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm trying to make a simple bot that will give out a role to a person who just joined the server.

The code:

```
import discord
import os
from discord.utils import get

bot_acces_token = os.environ['token']

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, id="123456789")
  await client.add_roles(member, role)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('Bot is ready')

client.run(bot_acces_token)
```

but unfortunately I get this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 17, in on_member_join
    role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, id="123456789")
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'server'
```

Comment: The way you are trying to add role is outdated.

Comment: `server` is not a valid attribute for any part in discordpy. The attribute is actually `guild`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your are trying to get the result is old and have changed.

You need to change the way you are defining your bot. You need to change this piece of code:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

You have to use `Command API` to use `event`. Change these lines to:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

Add an import statement as well on the top of the script:

```
from discord.ext import commands
```

Remove this as well:

```
from discord.utils import get
```

Try this instead:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id="123456789")
  await member.add_roles(role)
```

You need to use `member.guild.roles` instead of the one you have actually used. Also you need to use `await member.add_roles(role)` instead of the one you used. It would work for you. If you still have an error, ask away!

Thank You! :D

Comment: I tried this, but I get another error this time.

Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 18, in on_member_join
    await member.add_roles(role)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/member.py", line 777, in add_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: @OqOq Did you do all the things? I edited the answer.

Comment: Yes, I tried to do everything you told me to do but it gets me to the same error anyway.

Comment: @OqOq Don't worry! I will write you a code with proper explanation.

Comment: you shouldn't use "" because its an int data type

Comment: @OqOq Uh oh. I literally forgot this was something. Nvm.

Answer (score 0):

Thats the solution:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  channel = client.get_channel(1234567)
  role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=1234567)
  await member.add_roles(role)
```